# Search Value in array of string column posgres java

Tags: java, postgresql, specifications, hibernate-criteria

I have one column which is of string array in db.
`@Type(type = "com.here.tao.ctaas.jpa.entity.CustomStringArrayType") @Column(columnDefinition = "text[]") private String[] tags;`
In database column contains values as {'Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3'}

I am using Specification and overriding toPredicate() method for findAll() method .

`tags = ["tag1", "tag2"];

```
if(tags != null && !c.getTags().isEmpty()) {
            Expression<String> delimiter = builder.literal(",");
            tags.stream().forEach(tag -> {
                predicates.add(builder.like(
                        builder.function(
                                "array_to_string", String.class, root.get("tags"), delimiter),
                        "%" + tag.toLowerCase() + "%"));

            });

        }`
```

Problem with this is it returns if it find partial values too because of like query.

But my expectation is it should search exact word from the given array.

I tried with Predicate Function of jpa

Problem with this is it returns if it find partial values too because of like query.

But my expectation is it should search exact word from the given array.